# Ionic flexbox cannot set input vertical

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox, center

I used a flexbox to set my button in the middle of the page. But whatever I try, `justify-content: center` works, but `align-items: center` get just ignored.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<ion-content padding class="login">
  <div class="flex-container">
      <img src="assets/imgs/startbuttontext.png" class="flex-item" 
       style="height: 33vh;">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And here my CSS:

```css
.login {
    background: url(../assets/imgs/background1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;


    .flex-container {
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center !important;

        .flex-item {
            padding:0 10px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center !important;
            height: 33.3%;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height to the container element, rather than the item:

```
.flex-container {
    height: 33vh;
}
```

Comment: Also, I'd try to avoid using `!important`, unless you use f.i. Bootstrap which can have the nasty habit of overriding your styles unless you are REALLY specific.

Comment: right, but it doesn´t change the problem. !important i just tried, after it didn´t work

Comment: With the code you posted my answer should work. If it doesn't then there is something else in your code that conflicts. Try looking in your browsers devtools to find what causes the conflict.